# convert datetimestamp to time in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Am a newbie in python looking for some help.

I have imported a csv with my data and one of the columns has a date time stamp. As a dataframe, this is being read as type object e.g. 20.4.2018  07:57:00

How do I convert that column into time (or create a new column from the date time stamp which shows just time) without the date so that I can plot a graph based on the times.

Thank you.

Talch

Comment: Look at `time` module

Comment: Have you tried using the `parse_dates` option for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html ?

Comment: `dateutil.parser.parse(date_str)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strptime` from `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("20.4.2018 07:57:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 20, 7, 57)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your df is like this:

```
        date_time_info  value
0  2010.01.01 07:57:00      1
1  2010.01.01 07:58:00      2
2  2010.01.01 07:59:00      3
```

Use this:

```
df['date_time_info'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time_info']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
  date_time_info  value
0       07:57:00      1
1       07:58:00      2
2       07:59:00      3
```

### EDIT

To plot, you could do in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df['date_time_info'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time_info'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(df['date_time_info'], df['value'], linestyle='None', marker='.', markersize=10)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Joe, this works ok, and when I run df.head(5) I can see the effect of these changes, however Python still recognises that column as an object. I would need the data type to change from object so that I can use that column in a scatter plot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
dt = pd.to_datetime("20.4.2018 07:57:00", format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
time_only = dt.time()
```

The advantage is that [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) is vectorised, so you can apply it directly to the entire index/column.

Comment: I think the advantage of to_datetime is that you can specify the format. There could be ambiguous cases of american vs english convention (i.e. month or day first)

Comment: I think this is the best, as it uses Pandas' built-in functionality. Note that `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` seems to be identical to `df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64')`. (Which seems to me like a violation of PEP20, `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.` !)

Comment: although as @FLab points out, `to_datetime` seems to have more flexibility

Comment: Thank you folks, getting warmer..

How do I combine Joe & Flab's answer which is:

df['date_time_info'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time_info']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

but set this column to something like .astype('time64')

so that the data type is also changed

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_string = "20.4.2018 07:57:00"
dt_obj = datetime.strptime(timestamp_string, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(dt_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```